# React js doesn't load css in production

Tags: reactjs, production-environment

when I export my webapp for production (npm run-script build) and I upload the buid folder on my sever, it doesn't load the css.

I use
`import './Custom.css';` in my App.js file, and it works perfectly in the development environment.

Any idea about it? How could I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share your package.json

Comment: If your local environment is Window and production is the Linux server. So, maybe the capitalize 'C' is the cause

Answer (score 0):

### Hoops,

sorry for that.

You might want to check the `./Custom.css` file for some typo error. For example:

1. Is the **' C '** in Custom.css uppercase or lowercase?
2. May be you named one `custom.css` and imported `Custom.css` rather.

*I hope this safes you some stressed up time.*

Comment: No, actually it's loaded but not rendered :(